# In jsonpath how to put new value for nested json object?

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I have Json like this:

```
{
  "attachments": [
    "string"
  ],
  "contact": {
    "name": "Mahesh"
  },
  "contactCode": "C-0000001",
  "journalEntryCode": "JE-0000002",
  "linkedDocuments": [
    {
      "contactCode": "C-0000001",
      "documentCode": "0000018",
      "documentItemDetails": [
        {
          "productCode": "P-0000001"
        }
      ],
      "documentType": "QUOTATION",
    }
  ],
  "taxAmount": 2.322,
  "totalAmount": 12.322,
  "unitPriceGstInclusive": false
}
```

Under "linkedDocuments" I want to put/replace new value "1234" for "documentCode"
I tried following by taking json path:

```
JSONObject requestParams = Utilities.readJSON("createInvoiceFromQuote.json");

        requestParams.put("$.linkedDocuments[*].documentCode", "1234");
```

But it is just creating a new field "$.linkedDocuments[*].documentCode" at end of json like this

```
{
  "attachments": [
    "string"
  ],
  "contact": {
    "name": "Mahesh"
  },
  "contactCode": "C-0000001",
  "journalEntryCode": "JE-0000002",
  "linkedDocuments": [
    {
      "contactCode": "C-0000001",
      "documentCode": "0000018",
      "documentItemDetails": [
        {
          "productCode": "P-0000001"
        }
      ],
      "documentType": "QUOTATION",
    }
  ],
  "taxAmount": 2.322,
  "totalAmount": 12.322,
  "unitPriceGstInclusive": false
  "$.linkedDocuments[*].documentCode":"1234"
}
```

It should be like this

```
{
  "attachments": [
    "string"
  ],
  "contact": {
    "name": "Mahesh"
  },
  "contactCode": "C-0000001",
  "journalEntryCode": "JE-0000002",
  "linkedDocuments": [
    {
      "contactCode": "C-0000001",
      "documentCode": "1234",
      "documentItemDetails": [
        {
          "productCode": "P-0000001"
        }
      ],
      "documentType": "QUOTATION",
    }
  ],
  "taxAmount": 2.322,
  "totalAmount": 12.322,
  "unitPriceGstInclusive": false
}
```

How to I put/replace nested field value using java?

Comment: Have you tried requestParams.get("linkedDocuments").put("documentCode", "1234") ?

Comment: @NaveenBharadwaj It says "The method put(String, String) is undefined for the type Object"

Comment: Its because get method returns an Object. If you just cast it to JSONObject it should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since linkedDocuments is an JSONArray of JSONObject therefore "$.linkedDocuments[*].documentCode" key will not work as expected. To update any key of the JSONObject in JSONArray, access the JOSNArray and iterate on all the JSONObject and then perform the update.

```
String str = "{\"attachments\":[\"string\"],\"contact\":{\"name\":\"Mahesh\"},\"contactCode\":\"C-0000001\",\"journalEntryCode\":\"JE-0000002\",\"linkedDocuments\":[{\"contactCode\":\"C-0000001\",\"documentCode\":\"0000018\",\"documentItemDetails\":[{\"productCode\":\"P-0000001\"}],\"documentType\":\"QUOTATION\"},{\"contactCode\":\"C-0000002\",\"documentCode\":\"0000019\",\"documentItemDetails\":[{\"productCode\":\"P-0000002\"}],\"documentType\":\"QUOTATION\"}],\"taxAmount\":2.322,\"totalAmount\":12.322,\"unitPriceGstInclusive\":false}";

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);

JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("linkedDocuments");
array.getJSONObject(0).put("documentCode", 1234);
System.out.println(jsonObject);
```

Output:

```
{
  "linkedDocuments": [
    {
      "documentCode": 1234,
      "contactCode": "C-0000001",
      "documentType": "QUOTATION",
      "documentItemDetails": [
        {
          "productCode": "P-0000001"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "documentCode": "0000019",
      "contactCode": "C-0000002",
      "documentType": "QUOTATION",
      "documentItemDetails": [
        {
          "productCode": "P-0000002"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "totalAmount": 12.322,
  "attachments": [
    "string"
  ],
  "contactCode": "C-0000001",
  "contact": {
    "name": "Mahesh"
  },
  "journalEntryCode": "JE-0000002",
  "taxAmount": 2.322,
  "unitPriceGstInclusive": false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a minor correction in your code.

```
JSONObject requestParams = Utilities.readJSON("createInvoiceFromQuote.json");
JSONArray linkedDocuments = requestParams.getJSONArray("linkedDocuments");
JSONObject document = linkedDocuments.getJSONObject(0) 
document.put("documentCode", 1234);
```

Output

```
{
  "attachments": [
    "string"
  ],
  "contact": {
    "name": "Mahesh"
  },
  "contactCode": "C-0000001",
  "journalEntryCode": "JE-0000002",
  "linkedDocuments": [
    {
      "contactCode": "C-0000001",
      "documentCode": "1234",
      "documentItemDetails": [
        {
          "productCode": "P-0000001"
        }
      ],
      "documentType": "QUOTATION",
    }
  ],
  "taxAmount": 2.322,
  "totalAmount": 12.322,
  "unitPriceGstInclusive": false
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works for me. However since in above answer it has also been explained why my code was wrong so I have accepted it as an answer.